# How to write django model for nested category?

Tags: ajax, django, django-models, django-forms

I am making a Class note sharing django(2.1) website for college where categories and sub-categories will be nested:

```
|- Electronic
|- Mechanical
|      |- Automobile
|           |- Car Design
|- Chemistry
```

These categories and sub-categories will be created by admin-user and always can reorder them by changing its parent_id, category tables  stacked  nestedly as follows,

```
id  parent_id   category
---------------------------------
1   NULL        Electronic
2   NULL        Mechanical
3   2           Automobile
4   3           Car Design
5   NULL        Chemistry
```

So, What I need to make write a model for this.
I already made a blog with django(2.1), but I cant find out solution for this. Please help

**How to write a model for this?**

Comment: What exactly do you have troubles with?

Comment: How to write a model for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [django-mptt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)
to model your data structure. The relevant Django model would look like this:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
  parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='subcategories') 
  name = CharField(max_length=100)
```

Note that you don't strictly need `django-mptt` as you could always use 
the standard Django `ForeignKey` instead of `TreeForeignKey`,
but `django-mptt` makes lookups very efficient.